# Stoplight Simulator - White LED not turning on with button press

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, sketch, code-review

I am working on a relatively simple stoplight simulator that uses four LEDs - red, green, yellow, and white - in addition to a button. The 3 colored stoplight LEDs cycle as a real stoplight would. If the button is pressed while the green LED is on, the white light should turn on while the green light is still on (this can only be allowed to happen once). Previously, the stoplight cycle didn't work, but now the white light isn't turning on with the button press (see below)

Edit: The stoplight cycle now works, thanks to all your input, but the white light still doesn't come on when I press the button. This could be an issue using delay instead of millis(), but I'm not sure the easiest way to implement a fix. Any tips? My code is below. Thank you!

```
const int g_led = 3;
const int y_led = 4;
const int r_led = 5;
const int w_led = 6;
const int g_delay = 4000; //adjust test timings to reqs
const int y_delay = 2000;
const int r_delay = 3000;

int g_ledState;
int buttonState;
bool counter = false;

const int buttonPin = 2;

//green led function with conditional for white led
void green_light(){
  digitalWrite(g_led, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(y_led, LOW);
  digitalWrite(r_led, LOW);
  digitalWrite(w_led, LOW);
  g_ledState = 1;
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
if (buttonState == HIGH && g_ledState == 1 && counter == false){
  digitalWrite(w_led, HIGH);
    counter = true;
  }
  else{
    digitalWrite(w_led, LOW);
    counter = true;
  }
}

void yellow_light(){
  digitalWrite(y_led, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(g_led, LOW);
  digitalWrite(r_led, LOW);
  digitalWrite(w_led, LOW);
  g_ledState=0;
}

void red_light(){
  digitalWrite(r_led, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(y_led, LOW);
  digitalWrite(g_led, LOW);
  digitalWrite(w_led, LOW);
  g_ledState=0;
}

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(g_led, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(y_led, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(r_led, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(w_led, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
//main stoplight cycle
  green_light();
  delay(g_delay);
  yellow_light();
  delay(y_delay);
  red_light();
  delay(r_delay);
}
```

Comment: forget about your code for now ... write simple code to turn on one LED ... then change your code to turn on next LED .... when all LEDs are confirmed to work, then update your post to say that LEDs were tested

Comment: Your delays are very short - 20 and 50 msec. I would suggest you increase them, e.g. g_delay = 5000; for testing. You should see the green LED light up if it is wired correctly. Then you can move onto the other parts.

Comment: g_ledState will never be high at the time you are testing it in the conditional statement because it is set to low by the preceding red_light() call. Also counter is always forced to zero before you test its value. Maybe counter should be global or static.  Normally such exercises are designed to preclude the use of delay() for timing and require the explicit use of millis() instead. Have you external pull down resistors on the button pins?

Comment: That makes sense; the light cycle is working now but the white light still does not come on when I press the button. The counter is now global, and I have a pull down resistor on the button. I'm guessing using delay() is the issue, but I'm not very experienced in using millis(). Any tips on how that would work in this instance? I updated my code in the original question. Thank you all so much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to try it this way

```
allowed to happen once). My code compiles, but none of the lights turn on when I run it. I'm pretty sure I set the circuit correctly, so I want to see if I'm missing any issues in my code (below). Thank you!

//variables
const int g_led = 3;
const int y_led = 4;
const int r_led = 5;
const int w_led = 6;
const int g_delay = 1000;
const int y_delay = 500;
const int r_delay = 1000;
int g_ledState;
int buttonState;

const int buttonPin = 2;

//LED functions
void green_light(){

  int counter=0;

// conditional to let button turn on the white LED IF green LED is on and the white LED cycle hasn't already been run
if (buttonState == HIGH && g_ledState == 1 && counter == 0){
  digitalWrite(w_led, HIGH);
    counter =1;
  }
  else{
    digitalWrite(w_led, LOW);
    counter=0;
  }

  digitalWrite(g_led, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(y_led, LOW);
  digitalWrite(r_led, LOW);
  digitalWrite(w_led, LOW);
  g_ledState=1;
  button state=digitalRead(buttonPin);




}

void yellow_light(){
  digitalWrite(y_led, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(g_led, LOW);
  digitalWrite(r_led, LOW);
  digitalWrite(w_led, LOW);
  g_ledState=0;
}

void red_light(){
  digitalWrite(r_led, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(y_led, LOW);
  digitalWrite(g_led, LOW);
  digitalWrite(w_led, LOW);
  g_ledState=0;
}

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(g_led, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(y_led, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(r_led, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(w_led, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

//main stoplight cycle
  green_light();
  delay(g_delay);
  yellow_light();
  delay(y_delay);
  red_light();
  delay(r_delay);



}
```

Note that using delay is not that advisable but this way might help.

Here is another method using millis(), note that it hasn't been tested with arduino. If the compiling gives an error try modifying some things

```
//variables
const int g_led = 3;
const int y_led = 4;
const int r_led = 5;
const int w_led = 6;
const int g_delay;
const int y_delay;
const int r_delay;
int g_ledState;
int buttonState;
int oldbuttonState;
const int buttonPin = 2;

/* you can remove this one
Switch (white){
case 1:
//do nothing
break;

case 2 :
   buttonState=digitalRead(buttonPin);

   // conditional to let button turn on the white LED IF green LED is on and the white LED cycle hasn't already been run
if (buttonState == HIGH && counter == 0){
  digitalWrite(w_led, HIGH);
    counter =1;
  }
  else{
    digitalWrite(w_led, LOW);

  }   
counter=buttonState;
//switch to case 3
 white=3;
break;

case 3 :
//switch back to case two and continue reading the button
white=2;
break;
*/

}
//LED functions
void green_light(){

  digitalWrite(g_led, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(y_led, LOW);
  digitalWrite(r_led, LOW);
  digitalWrite(w_led, LOW);

// start reading the button
  // I added this for better performance
int rep=millis;
while((millis-rep) < 3000){
digitalRead(buttonpin);
if (buttonState == HIGH && counter == 0){
  digitalWrite(w_led, HIGH);
    counter =1;
  }
  else{
    digitalWrite(w_led, LOW);

  }   
counter=buttonState;

}
  g_delay=Millis();

}

void yellow_light(){
//stop button reading
  white=1;
  digitalWrite(y_led, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(g_led, LOW);
  digitalWrite(r_led, LOW);
  digitalWrite(w_led, LOW);
  y_delay=millis();

}

void red_light(){
 //stop button reading
  white=1
  digitalWrite(r_led, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(y_led, LOW);
  digitalWrite(g_led, LOW);
  digitalWrite(w_led, LOW);
  r_delay=millis();
}

Switch (cases){
//main stoplight cycle
case 1 :
  green_light();
  /// wait for 3 seconds
  if (millis() - g_delay >=3000){
     yellow_light();
}
 cases=2;
 break;

case 2 :
  /// wait 2 seconds
  if (millis() - y_delay >=2000){
     red_light();
}
cases=3;
break;

 case 3 :
 // wait 5 seconds 
  if (millis() - r_delay >=5000){
      cases=1;
}
cases=1;
break;

}

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(g_led, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(y_led, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(r_led, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(w_led, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
cases=1;


}
```

It haven't been tested but just try it out

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot! I've been messing around with the first version of your modifications, as it seems to work the most smoothly. Although the light cycle is working now, the white light still does not come on on the button press. Could it be because the delays are interrupting the conditional in green_light() from executing? I'm not very experienced in using millis(), but if that would be the solution, I'd appreciate some guidance on how to implement it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any circuit details... SO...

Where most indicator LEDs need 2 to 2.2 volts and 8 to 25mA,
white LEDs typically need 3.1V and 25mA minimum to turn on.

Also micro processors have limits to the current a pin can deliver
If you are using a 3.3v micro not all the voltage will make it to the LED.

look up the spec sheets on the micro and white LED.  I have a feeling you are going to find either the micro pin or the supply an issue.

Try switching out a colored LED for testing the code.
If the LED works then try going to some driver circuit to power the white LED.